# Typoscript Use value in Text Wrap multiple times

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

In a Templavoila FCE i want to achieve the following from an input field:

```
<a name="Inputvalue">Inputvalue</>
```

My current Setup is the following:

```
10 = TEXT
10.current = 1
10.wrap = <a name="|"> | </a>
```

But for sure, it just fill out the first pipe:

```
<a name="Inputvalue"></a>
```

Any Idea how to achieve that in a simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!

I did it this way:

```
10 = COA
10 {
    wrap = |

    10 = TEXT
    10.current = 1
    10.rawUrlEncode = 1
    10.wrap = <a name="|">

    20 = TEXT
    20.current = 1
    20.wrap = | </a>
}
```